# HAProxy to terminate SSL also send SSL to backend server

Tags: haproxy

I would like terminate SSL at HAProxy, do some manipulation on the header, rewrite URL and re-encrypt traffic and send to backend servers as SSL?

I can't seem to find a way to do this. I can get regular SSL termination done, and send plain HTTP requests to backend. But I need to send SSL to backend.

I would like to have the following features:

- Extract x-forwarded-for headers, to get the real client IP behind proxy.
- Implement session stickiness using cookie.
- Do some URL rewriting.
- Send SSL traffic to backend using cookie based session stickieness.

Unless I terminate SSL at haproxy end, I cannot get URL rewriting done.

Any help from the good people here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your current config, and tell us what's not working?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's nothing special to do in haproxy.cfg. You simply configure whatever URL rewrites and header manipulations you want within your HAProxy frontend and then redirect traffic to your SSL backend. Here's an quick example:

```
frontend app1_ssl
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs.d/example.com.crt crt /etc/haproxy/certs.d/ no-sslv3

    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Port 443
   
    # set HTTP Strict Transport Security (HTST) header
    http-response add-header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000

    # some ACLs and URL rewrites...

    default_backend             backend_app1_ssl


backend backend_app1_ssl
    server mybackendserver 127.0.0.1:4433 ssl verify none
```

Comment: Awesome! Let me try that. I wasn't able to find that "server .... ssl" thing anywhere.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I was able to get it working. However, I could not get SSL sticky to work. Could you help please? The question is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/738397/haproxy-ssl-roundrobin-not-working-when-ssl-terminated-and-forwarded

Comment: Great, I'm glad I was able to help. Don't forget to accept my answer so others can see right away that it was helpful ;-)

Comment: Does the encryption really works by by giving ssl verify none? From the haproxy documentation, " If set
to 'none', server certificate is not verified. In the other case, The
certificate provided by the server is verified using CAs from 'ca-file'". Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: With `ssl verify none` traffic between HAProxy and backend server is still encrypted, but validity of backend's SSL certificate isn't checked.

Comment: I just found this answer and discovered I had already upvoted it... Wish I could upvote again! Thanks!

Comment: according to (\*) `reqadd` is an old directive and `https-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https` can be used. (\*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51940105/4940240 from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51928504/x-forwarded-proto-https-in-frontend-or-backend-haproxy/51940105#51940105). (just noting)

Comment: @eli you are right. Deprecation warning was added after my initial answer. I've updated my answer. Cheers!

Comment: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#5.2-ssl
the `server` keywords support a lot of interesting settings, documented here.